# Android: get sent messages (outbox)?

Tags: android

As broadcast Receiver listen new incoming messages just like that whenever a new message is sent how to get that message and its details.

```
 public class incomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


            try {

                if (bundle != null) {

                    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                        SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);

                        String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                        String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                        Date date = new Date(currentMessage.getTimestampMillis());
                        String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);

                        long time=date.getTime();
                        String formattedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").format(time);

                        Toast.makeText(context,"recieved sms "+"senderNum: "+ phoneNumber + ", message: " + message+ " , date:" + formattedDate + ",time: "+formattedTime , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        MyDBHandler db = new MyDBHandler(context);

                        int f_id=1;
                        db.insertDat2(new DataSetGet(f_id,phoneNumber,message,formattedDate,formattedTime));
    //                    addData(phoneNumber,message,formattedDate,formattedTime);

                    } // end for loop
                } // bundle is null

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

            }


            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;


            if (bundle != null) {

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                    String no = "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
                    String message= msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context,"sent message "+"no: "+no+" message: "+ message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }


        }
```

Now toast is not appearing when I'm sending message.

1. running application.
2. sending message to a number.
3. toast doesn't appear.
4. receive message from that number
5. now toast of sent message appears

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

add this in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Put this code in activity file:

```
// Create Sent box URI
Uri sentURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(sentURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```

You will get all sending message received in this receiver.Now you can store message in sqlite  database.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i need .I had done this portion. Broadcast Receiver is used to listen incoming messages but i'm asking about outbox , outgoing messages

Comment: @fatima can you please check my code.
android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED 

is getting outbox messages not getting inbox messages,

Comment: Thanks it is working but only when i receive message from that number only then it is getting sent message

Comment: if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                // Sender's phone number
        String no = "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
        String message= msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        Toast.makeText(context,"sent message "+"no: "+no+" message: "+ message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}

Comment: but toast is showing only when i receive message from that number

Comment: above i'm writing whole class please check

Comment: check this link https://rahulmehta1.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/android-reading-inbox-and-sent-box-sms/

Comment: actually i d'nt want to do this with uri. I want my application to work like this

Comment: 1. install     2. retrieve all messages inbox,sent using uri     3. using broadcast receiver get new incoming messages  4. get new outgoing messages                tats why i dn't want to fetch sent messages using uri